# PubSub topic name as ValueProvider in Dataflow python throws TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there an option to pass topic name as input?
This is a simple example

```
  class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument(
      '--input-topic',
      default='projects/project/topics/test'
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

  c_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(MyOptions)
  pipline_options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True, save_main_session=True)

  with Pipeline(options=pipline_options) as pipeline:
    (
      pipeline
      | io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=c_options.input_topic)
      | io.WriteToText('...')
    )
```

when I'm tryign to build a template

```
  python -m main \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project project \
    --staging_location gs://.../staging \
    --temp_location gs://.../temp \
    --template_location gs://.../templates/mytemp \
    --region eu-west1
```

I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/me/dataflow/iot/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    | io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=c_options.input_topic).with_output_types(bytes)
  File "/home/me/dataflow/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py", line 256, in __init__
    self._source = _PubSubSource(
  File "/home/me/dataflow/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py", line 459, in __init__
    self.project, self.topic_name = parse_topic(topic)
  File "/home/me/dataflow/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py", line 403, in parse_topic
    match = re.match(TOPIC_REGEXP, full_topic)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 190, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I saw similiar problem here [Dataflow Error providing pubsub topic as arugument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550623/dataflow-error-providing-pubsub-topic-as-arugument)
but there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `add_value_provider_argument` in your option, you can use an usual `String` with `add_argument` :

```py
class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_argument("--input_topic", default='projects/project/topics/test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

  c_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(MyOptions)
  pipline_options = PipelineOptions(streaming=True, save_main_session=True)

  with Pipeline(options=pipline_options) as pipeline:
    (
      pipeline
      | io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=c_options.input_topic)
      | io.WriteToText('...')
    )
```

There was also a typo in your option name : `--input-topic`

and in the invocation from the pipeline : `input_topic`

In my example I used `input_topic` in the 2 places.

Comment: @ponczkowyjegomosc have you tested my proposition ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [pubsub.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py), it doesn't look like Pub/Sub topic name can be provided as a ValueProvider argument. Have you tried using [Dataflow Flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates), where you do not have to use ValueProviders for specifying dynamic arguments ?